# Bring the HTML text infront of CSS rgba layer

Tags: html, css

Here is a screenshoot on my work :

[image]

So I have 3 layer at that pic :

1. Image layer
2. RGBA dark grey (low opacity) layer
3. Text layer

I want the HTML text is not covered by rgba grey layer. I've trying it like this :

```
   <div style="some background image"> //bg image
      <div className="greyLayer"></div> //greyLayer
          <div>
             //Text
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

But it instead makes the grey layer not visibel at all.

Here is the full code that implement like in the pic

> Header.js

```
<div className="card card-image" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${jumbotronImg})`, backgroundSize: "cover", backgroundBlendMode: ""}}>
                <div className="greyLayer"></div>
                    <div className="text-white text-center rgba-stylish-strong">
                        <div className="py-3">
                            <h5 className="h5 orange-text"><i className="fas fa-camera-retro"></i> Photography</h5>
                            <h2 className="card-title h2 my-4 py-2">ToDo List App</h2>
                            <p className="mb-4 pb-2 px-md-5 mx-md-5"></p>
                            <a className="btn peach-gradient"><i className="fas fa-clone left"></i> View project</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

> Header.css

```
.greyLayer {
    background-color: rgba(46, 49, 49, 1);
    opacity: 50%;
}
```

I'm working on a React project btw. Don't know if it do a thing with it

Answer (score 0):

You can change your markup so that the text is a sibling with the low opacity layer:

```
<div style="some background image"> <!-- bg image -->
    <div className="greyLayer"></div> <!-- greyLayer -->
    <div className="textDiv">
        Text
    </div>
</div>
```

After that, you can have the text to have a higher z-index so that it stays on top of the low opacity layer.

```
.textDiv {
    position: relative; /* give any other position value other than static for z-index to take effect */
    z-index: 20;
}
```